# OpenMP not available on mac with gcc 4.9

Tags: macos, gcc, openmp, gcc4.9

The OpenMP website says: "GCC 4.9 supports OpenMP 4.0 for C/C++".

I'm using gcc 4.9.1 from brew, yet I see this error when I try to compile liblinear: `omp.h file not found`.

Specifically:

```
Compiling liblinear version 1.93
Source code page:
   http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/
external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/matlab/train.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.

    mex: compile of ' "external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/matlab/train.cpp"' failed.
```

Here's the matlab code used to compile liblinear, which contains a file that contains `#include <omp.h>`:

```
% Compile liblinear
if ~exist('liblinear_train')
  fprintf('Compiling liblinear version 1.93\n');
  fprintf('Source code page:\n');
  fprintf('   http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/\n');

  mex -outdir bin ...
      COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS -fopenmp" -largeArrayDims ...
      external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/matlab/train.cpp ...
      external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/matlab/linear_model_matlab.cpp ...
      external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/linear.cpp ...
      external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/tron.cpp ...
      "external/liblinear-1.93_multicore/blas/*.c" ...
      -output liblinear_train;
end`
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the gcc version in mexopts.sh (side note: I copied it from `/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/bin/mexopts.sh` to `~/.matlab/R2013a`). Specifically, I changed `CC=xcrun  -sdk macosx10.9  clang` to `CC='gcc-4.9'`.

I think Matlab does indeed use this compiler, because when I run this code:

```
if ~exist('anigauss')
    fprintf('Compiling the anisotropic gauss filtering of:\n');
    fprintf('   J. Geusebroek, A. Smeulders, and J. van de Weijer\n');
    fprintf('   Fast anisotropic gauss filtering\n');
    fprintf('   IEEE Transactions on Image Processing, 2003\n');
    fprintf('Source code/Project page:\n');
    fprintf('   http://staff.science.uva.nl/~mark/downloads.html#anigauss\n\n');
    mex -Dchar16_t=uint16_T -outdir bin ...
        selective_search/SelectiveSearchCodeIJCV/Dependencies/anigaussm/anigauss_mex.c ...
        selective_search/SelectiveSearchCodeIJCV/Dependencies/anigaussm/anigauss.c ...
        -output anigauss
end
```

Matlab prints:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mpfr2/lib/libmpfr.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.1/cc1
  Reason: Incompatible library version: cc1 requires version 4.0.0 or later, but libmpfr.1.dylib provides version 3.0.0
gcc-4.9: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1)
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/bin/mex: line 1343: 77128 Abort trap: 6           gcc-4.9 -c -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/extern/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fno-common -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -Dchar16_t=uint16_T -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O2 -DNDEBUG "selective_search/SelectiveSearchCodeIJCV/Dependencies/anigaussm/anigauss_mex.c" -o bin/anigauss_mex.o

    mex: compile of ' "selective_search/SelectiveSearchCodeIJCV/Dependencies/anigaussm/anigauss_mex.c"' failed.
```

Yet when I try to compile liblinear, I get the very same error message as usual.

Comment: What command are you trying to use to compile with?

Comment: I'm trying to use SPP_net, which depends on liblinear. See https://github.com/ShaoqingRen/SPP_net. It's a neural net used for object detection in images.

Comment: So that was `gcc -I ? -L ? how who where when`?

Answer (score 2):

```
COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /openmp" -largeArrayDims ...
                      ^^^^^^^
```

This was probably written for Microsoft Visual C/C++ or for Intel C/C++ Compiler on Windows. Unix systems, including OS X, traditionally use `-` to denote command line flags.

To enable OpenMP support in GCC you should change `/openmp` to `-fopenmp` in the compiler flags `COMPFLAGS`.

---

It appears that in addition to passing the wrong OpenMP flag, `mex` is using the wrong compiler. Compare the error outputs from GCC and Clang:

GCC

```
foo.c:1:25: fatal error: nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <nonexistent.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

Clang

```
foo.c:1:10: fatal error: 'nonexistent.h' file not found
#include <nonexistent.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Clang, or at least the version that Apple ships with Xcode, does not support OpenMP. Consult the MATLAB documentation of the [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html) command on how to select a different compiler. Basically, you have to execute:

```
mex -setup
```

If MATLAB detects several usable compilers, it should present you with the ability to pick one of them. Unfortunately, according to [this table](http://www.mathworks.de/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html?sec=maci64), MATLAB might not support GCC on OS X (at least it is not listed in the table).

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error. I updated the code in the question to show what I executed. Before running the command, `$COMPFLAGS` is empty.

Comment: @RosePerrone, I didn't notice initially that the error message is not one that GCC would give. See the newly added part. Basically, you have to change your question to "How do I tell MATLAB to use a different compiler?"